# sort and swap in python same time

Tags: python

> Enter first string:abbc
>
> Enter second string:aAaabbccCCcccddeeffffggzba
>
> Letters Found a:5 Letters Found b:3 Letters Found c:7
>
> final [5, 3, 7] emptylist ['a', 'b', 'c']
>
> the 2nd one
>
> ================== RESTART: /Users/Handy/Documents/task3.py ================== Enter first string:badcefdke
>
> Enter second string:dkenzmdnfer
>
> Letters Found d:2 Letters Found e:2 Letters Found f:1 Letters Found
>   k:1
>
> final [2, 2, 1, 1]
>
> emptylist ['d', 'e', 'f', 'k']

i need help so that in the first one i can print the highest numbber and its letter correctly in order. if i sort final from highest to lowest, i wouldn't want to sort emptylist but i would've swap it . But how do i swap it without using a function? thanks

Comment: You forgot to provide the code.

Comment: Pls explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Does `final, emptylist = zip(*sorted(zip(final, emptylist), reverse=True))` do what you want?

Comment: im trying to print the numbers of second string that occurs in first string

Comment: Dear Rawing! That works perfectly fine. But i don't want to use built in function such as sort and reverse. I need the algorithm or the function to call it

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

This tallies repeated characters in a dictionary and then creates a list of the sorted (sorted using max() and dict.pop(key, None)) values

```
first_str = input('Enter first string >').strip()
second_str = input('Enter second string >').strip()

first_str = first_str.lower()
first_str = set(first_str)
second_str = second_str.lower()

counts = {}

for character in first_str:
    counts [character] = second_str.count(character)

counts_list = []
popdict = {k: v for k,v in counts.items()}
for k in counts:
    key, value = max(popdict, key=popdict.get),max(popdict.values())
    counts_list.append([key,value])
    popdict.pop(key, None)

for sublist in counts_list:
    print (sublist[0]+' = '+str(sublist[1]))
```

prints:

```
[['c', 7], ['a', 5], ['b', 3]]
c = 7
a = 5
b = 3
```

Comment: i want it do be highest number of occurence to lowest  d = 2 e =2 f  = 1 k = 1. another example c=7 b=5 a=3

Comment: @HandyHasan I have made a change to the answer to try to get your output

Comment: @HandyHasan are you allowed to use max() ?